# Use Rails Logger with Savon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, savon

I have the following code:

```
  def soap_client
    soap_client = Savon.client(
        wsdl: "https://api.five9.com/wsadmin/AdminWebService?wsdl&user=apiloader@daxko.com",
        namespace: "http://service.admin.ws.five9.com/",
        headers: {"Authorization" =>  "Basic #{@realm}"},
        env_namespace: :soapenv,
        namespace_identifier: :ser,
        ssl_verify_mode: :none,
        logger: Rails.logger,
        log: true
    )
  end
```

This works and logs everything to my console window. However, it doesn't actually log anything to the `Rails.logger`...

How can I use the default `Rails.logger` with Savon?

## EDIT

I am using savon (2.3.2).

Comment: Maybe that will help you: https://github.com/savonrb/savon/issues/370

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I was actually trying something similar to this, but I kept getting a "undefined method `config`" error. I did some research and it seemed like this was caused due to having an outdated version of Savon, so I updated the most recent version and still receive the undefined method error.

Comment: @Luigi you might need to update your answer with the configure portion of Savon

Comment: I have posted more information here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858938/grab-specific-data-from-soap-api-response-using-ruby-and-savon

My question is a little different there, so I will leave both open for the time being.